# Spring Data method name to retrieve multiple columns

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have a document in which I want to query with spring data method by these fields `createdDate` and `userID`: something like `findByUserIdAndCreatedDate(userId)`. Is it possible to do such kind of thing only passing the `userId` and expect it to sorted with created date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find by `userId` and sort by `createdDate` you can use syntax like:

```
public User findByUserIdOrderByCreatedDateDesc(Long userId);
public User findByUserIdOrderByCreatedDateAsc(Long userId);
```

Spring Data's method name query generation will expect a method with a name like `findByUserIdAndCreatedDate` to have two parameters (`Long userId, Date createdDate`), but since you omitted it in the method signature, it will likely fail during repository startup.

You can get more information on Spring Data method name query keywords in the spring.io guide: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.6.x/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Great! Glad that it was.